# How can I exec() my program in c?

Tags: c

I am trying to run my program in c using the execl () function.
Currently, the piece of code that should run the program looks like this, and info_proc is in a info_proc.c file with a main containing a printf.

```
`switch(fork()) {
   case -1:
      perror("fork");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   case 0:
      getcwd(dir, 256);
      strcat(dir, "/info_proc");
      printf("dir %s", dir);
      execl(dir, "info_proc", req->data, NULL);
      perror("execl");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    default:
      wait(NULL);
      break;
}
```

`

My program returns "execl: bad address" to the execution ... I do not really see where the error can come from

Comment: Is there something in `req->data` that we should know about?

Comment: Can't say. You don't provide a [mcve], so we don't have declarations of things like `dir` and `req`.

Comment: Note that `req->data` must be a string.

Comment: req->data is a pid. And dir is the complet epath to the custom program  info_proc. He is initialized before the switch : char *dir = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);

Comment: What type is `req->data`?  If `pid_t` (or `int`) then you should convert it to a zero delimited string.

Comment: Yes req->data is a pid_t... i will try this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my problem was that req->data was a pid_t.
Here is how I solved my problem (thanks to cdark, usr2564301 and Fred Larson !!)

```
char *dir = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    switch(fork()) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0:
            getcwd(dir, 256);
            strcat(dir, "/info_proc");
            printf("dir %s", dir);
            char *pid = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
            sprintf(pid, "%d", req->data);
            execl(dir, "info_proc", pid, NULL);
            perror("execl");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        default:
            wait(NULL);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: If you had entered `execl: bad address` into your search engine you would have found a number of duplicates.  By the way, why are you using `malloc` for the string rather than a character array (you can put a `{ }` block in the `case`)?  Anyway, consider `snprintf` for safety`.